# CSS 3D Cube Revisted; 3D Room

Tags: css, 3d, transform

I am trying to create a 'room' that the visitor is 'sat' in the middle of, watching it spin around them. Kind of like being drunk :D

I started with a few tutorials on making a cube and getting it to spin. From there, it didn't take me long to realise that by playing with the cube size and the overall perspective amount, I can cut off some faces of the cube while they rotate 'behind' the visitor.

**See here (works on FF and Chrome I believe): http://jsfiddle.net/jq2j7/**

Perspective is set at 50em.
Cube 'size' is 100em, double the perspective, thus (I suspect) placing the 'camera' in the center of the cube.

**So this kinda works for me, but the room is not big enough. I'd like it to be more 'school hall' size rather than 'garden shed' size. This is where I am having trouble.**

If I decrease the overall perspective I can get the room to look bigger, but with a kind of fish eye effect. If I increase the cube size, the 'camera' gets pushed back out of the cube.

I would have thought I could simply translateZ the whole cube towards or away from the screen as needed, but I haven't been able to achieve that (I tried a transform: translateZ(50em) on the .cube and even on the body but to no effect).

I'm fairly certain that tying the size of the cube to the scene perspective just to get 'camera position' correct is probably not the best way to go about this, so if anyone can point me in the right direction... :D

Thanks!

---

Code is straightforward enough, as follows:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="cube">
    <li></li><!-- Front -->
    <li></li><!-- Back -->
    <li></li><!-- Right -->
    <li></li><!-- Left -->
    <li></li><!-- Top -->
    <li></li><!-- Bottom -->
</ul>
```

**CSS**
(I havent included BG images here so note this would render an invisible cube :P)

```
@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    perspective: 50em;
    -webkit-perspective: 50em;
}

.cube, .cube li {
    position: absolute;

    width: 100em;
    height: 100em;
}

.cube {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    margin-top: -50em;
    margin-left: -50em;

    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 25s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 25s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

    list-style-type: none;
}

.cube > li {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.cube > li:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(50em);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(50em);
}

.cube > li:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(50em);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(50em);
}

.cube > li:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50em);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50em);
}

.cube > li:nth-child(4) {
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50em);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50em);
}

.cube > li:nth-child(5) {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50em);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50em);
}

.cube > li:nth-child(6) {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50em);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50em);
}
```

Comment: Ok I was going to delete this question to save embarrassment but perhaps there is still a better solution.... I just altered the texture to show much smaller bricks and indeed the room looks much bigger now. I'm still not sure about about the perspective/cube size being 'tied together' though.

Comment: Extra note; on my own demo I made the bricks smaller. It does make the room look bigger; but not enough to fool my eyes into thinking the room is the size I want. So I do think some code changes are needed after all, not just my textures :D